# I am trying to mount my SD Card using Debian 10

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, sd-card

This is the command I am sending:

```
sudo mount /mnt/chromeos/removable/SDCard /mnt/mydrive
```

This is what I get back:

```
sudo mount /mnt/chromeos/removable/SDCard /mnt/mydrive
mount: /mnt/mydrive: permission denied.
```

I'm trying to move my Apache2 web directory to this SD card

Comment: What's `/mnt/chromeos/removable/SDCard`? Are you bind mounting or what?

Comment: I was hoping to us the sd card to store images for my website but despite being mounted, I was unable to get html links to the drive to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the mount point before you can use it.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mydrive
```

**Edit**

Looking back at your command more carefully, I realize that you don't appear to be trying to mount a *device* such as */dev/sde*. */mnt/chromeos/removable/SDCard* is already a mount point.

What do you see with:

```
sudo ls -lh /mnt/chromeos/removable/SDCard
```

Do you have a "**Disks**" GUI application available? Typically it's in *Accessories*. Open **Disks** and look for your SDcard.

Alternatively use:

```
blkid
```

and look for your SDcard.

Comment: Did that already.

Comment: udo mkdir /mnt/mydrive
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/mydrive’: File exists

Comment: @Robert Hull - That sugests you have a **file** in your /mnt directory named mydrive. Do an **ls -lh /mnt/mydrive**. Delete the file and try again, or simply **sudo mkdir /mnt/mydrive2**.

Comment: ls -lh /mnt/mydrive
total 0